# Multiple columns and the IN operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, multiple-columns

There is a table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TestTable
    ( id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL
    , data1 VARCHAR(255) NULL
    , data2 VARCHAR(255) NULL
    , data3 VARCHAR(255) NULL
    )
```

... and some sample data:

```
INSERT  INTO dbo.TestTable
VALUES    ( 'some data'  , 'some other data'  , 'and another')
        , ( 'some data 2', 'some other data 2', 'and another 2')
        , ( 'some data 3', 'some other data 3', 'and another 3')
        , ( 'some data 4', 'some other data 4', 'and another 4')
        , ( 'some data 5', 'some other data 5', 'and another 5')
        , ( 'some data 6', 'some other data 6', 'and another 6')
```

... and finally a simple SELECT query:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.TestTable tt 
WHERE  tt.data1 IN ('x', 'y', 'z')
    OR tt.data2 IN ('x', 'y', 'z')
    OR tt.data3 IN ('x', 'y', 'z')
```

*Note: in my actual scenario both the number of values in the IN operator and the number of dataXX columns are much larger.*

As you can see, the list of values sought ('x', 'y', 'z') is repeated multiple times. I am looking for a "smarter" way of building this query, purely to avoid copying the "OR tt.dataXX in (...)" line many, many times.

Is there any way I could use the ('x', 'y', 'z') list of values just ONCE in the above SELECT query and have all tt.dataXX columns covered?

If so, what is it?

Comment: With a bad database design you will get bad queries, no way around that. Why do you have 3 different columns that seemingly contain the same type of data? (and by "type", I do not mean string or number, I mean "meaning")

Comment: Lasse, while I appreciate your advice (and agree with you 120%, no doubts), there is a difference between working in an academic environment where everyone adheres to golden standards, and a real business scenario where you depend on others' work and you have to go ahead with whatever you have, and with limited resources. I agree this is a suboptimal data structure but it is what it is for reasons outside of scope for this question.

Comment: And in the real world we copy paste

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't test it here, but you should be able to do something like this using the [table value constructor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx).

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.TestTable tt
WHERE EXIST (
    SELECT 1
    FROM (VALUES ('x'), ('y'), ('z')) AS b(Name)
    WHERE b.Name IN (tt.data1, tt.data2, tt.data3)
)
```

Comment: Bull's eye, sir! With a tiny correction, it works:

 SELECT *
 FROM dbo.TestTable tt
 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT b.Name
      FROM ( VALUES ( 'x'), ( 'y'), ( 'z') ) AS b ( Name )
      WHERE b.Name IN ( tt.data1, tt.data2, tt.data3 ) )